# Porquê usar contemporaneamente float:left e display:inline?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Estou a ver um tutorial, onde o professor a um certo momento, [minuto 28](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eOG90Q8EfRo&spfreload=10%20Message%3A%20JSON%20Parse%20error%3A%20Unexpected%20EOF%20(url%3A%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DeOG90Q8EfRo)), estabelece o style do elementos duma `ul` para criar uma *barra de navegação horizontal*, e fa-lo usando seja o `float:left` que o `display:inline`. O problema é que eu ontem tinha visto que os métodos que citei em cima são dois métodos diferentes para obter a barra horizontal, mas então porque ele usa os dois contemporaneamente?

```
.mainheader nav ul li{
    float:left; /* li are set to the left of their "brothers"*/
    display:inline;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Geralmente, elementos flutuados têm um valor de display [definido implicitamente](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo) como `block`. Porém, o caso dos itens de lista é uma exceção. Segundo a especificação,

> no CSS 2.1 não é definido se valores `list-item` deverão assumir o valor computado `block` ou `list-item`.

<sup>(tradução livre)</sup>

No Chrome, [por exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/098fon9v/), os itens de lista flutuados deixam sobrar os *bullets*. Acredito que a intenção de incluir `display: inline` na regra foi justamente de eliminar esses *bullets*, forçando que os `<li>` flutuados assumam `display: block` em vez de `display: list-item`.

Comment: Nota: removi minha resposta anterior, pois estava incorreta.

Answer (score 1):

Estas duas instruções do permitem que os elementos html `<li>` sejam dispostas um do lado do outro pois por padrão o `CSS` mostra uma lista não ordenada (`<ul>`) ou ordenada (`<ol>`) cujo elementos estarão um embaixo uns dos outros.

> Assim aparecerão um item abaixo do outro.

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>Item 01</li>
        <li>Item 02</li>
        <li>Item 03</li>
        <li>Item 04</li>
        <li>Item 05</li>
    </ul> 
</nav>
```

> Assim aparecerá um item ao lado do outro.

```
<style>
    /* Remove os pontos dos itens da lista */
    nav ul { list-style:none }

    /* Colocá-os (`<li>`) um ao lado do outro - Pode ser um ou outro */
    nav ul li { display:inline; display:inline-block; } 

    /* float: left me parece desnecessário neste caso. */
</style>

<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>Item 01</li>
        <li>Item 02</li>
        <li>Item 03</li>
        <li>Item 04</li>
        <li>Item 05</li>
    </ul> 
</nav>
```

Comment: Já viu isto aqui? [*Apresentando: JS, CSS e HTML executáveis!*](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2115/201) :)

Comment: ps, faltou encapsular o `<ul>` com o `<nav>`... ou remover o `nav` do CSS.

Comment: Não havia reparado a ferramenta, imagino que ela tenha se adicionada conforme minha reputação alcançou uma determinada pontuação.

Comment: @MarcosVinicius Essa ferramenta é nova, foi acrescentada [ao SOpt] só ontem, mas está disponível pra todos os usuários.

Answer (score 0):

Display é pra fazer o elemento se comportar como block ou inline de acordo com o box model... Já o Float tira o elemento do fluxo padrão, fazendo com q flutue como se fosse uma layer... definindo a camada por meio do z-index... Então pode-se usar por exemplo os dois ao mesmo tempo sempre que vc quiser q um elemento se comporte como bloco ou inline e q ainda saia do fluxo

Comment: O que z-index tem haver com float?

Comment: quis dizer apenas q o z-index pode ser usando junto com o float... q um não impede o outro... ajustando a ordem na pilha de layers... tipo neste exemplo... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579753/css-floating-w-overlap

Comment: `z-index` com `float`? Pensei que `z-index` requeria `position` (`relative`, `absolute` ou `fixed`)...  Leia por favor: http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/z-index Note: O OP da questão está falando de `float:;` e não de `position:;`